# Why does my code show run time error (NZEC), while I run it on codechef (gcc 4.8.1)?

Tags: c, gcc, runtime-error

Problem:Your program is to use the brute-force approach in order to find the Answer to Life, the Universe, and Everything. More precisely... rewrite small numbers from input to output. Stop processing input after reading in the number 42. All numbers at input are integers of one or two digits.
Example

```
Input:
1
2
88
42
99

Output:
1
2
88
```

My try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main ()
{
    int number;

    do 
    {
        scanf("%d",&number);

        if (number != 42)
        {
            printf("%d\n",number);
        }
    }while (number != 42);
}
```

Comment: Taking a leap of faith here and guessing "NZEC" means "Non-zero exit code", i.e. your program failed to `return 0;` to the calling environment

Comment: By not returning an `int`, the program is not actually standard C compliant. The C standard specifies that `main` *must* return `int`.

Comment: Why my post is downvoted ? is there something wrong in not knowing something ? I presented my question clearly I guess. I received good amount of answers as well.

Answer (score 2):

I ran your code and had the error:

warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain-return-type]
void main ()

however it was gcc version 4.2.1

I fixed it by changing the type declaration of void to int and adding a return 0.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int number;

    do
    {
            scanf("%d",&number);

            if (number != 42)
            {
                    printf("%d\n",number);
            }

    }while (number != 42);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`NZEC` stands for `non-zero exit code`, which means that your `main` function doesn't return zero.

If you run your code on codechef, the `main` function **has to return zero**, otherwise codechef thinks your programs don't exit successfully.

Always reminds yourself:

```
int main()
{
    // some code
    return 0;
}
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // some code
    return 0;
}
```

`void main` is a **non-standard** extension in C programming language, and is **forbidden** in C++ programming language.

P.S.

ISO C 90/99/11 standard, section 5.1.2.2.1, Program startup:

> The function called at program startup is named **main**. The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It shall
>   be defined with a return type of **int** and with no parameters:
>
> ```
>     int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as **argc** and **argv**, though any
>   names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
>   declared):
>
> ```
>     int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent; or in some other implementation-defined manner.

ISO C++ 98/03/11 standard, section 3.6.1, Main function:

> An implementation shall not predefine the **main** function. This function
>   shall not be overloaded. It shall have a return type of type **int**, but
>   otherwise its type is implementation-defined. All implementations
>   shall allow both the following definitions of **main**:
>
> ```
>     int main() { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
>     int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```